# How do I add a header to every http request coming from Phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

is there a simple way to create a plugin (IOS/Android) that would add a HTTP Header to every outgoing request?

Comment: Did you create such plugin?

Comment: Yep; but  I doubt I have the code lying around 4 years later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create `BroadcastReceiver` and listen on outgoing requests. Edit the received content and send it after this.

Helpful Articles on this topic:

- [Android Developer reference page about `BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
- [A Stack Overflow question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140061/broadcast-receiver-and-internet-connection)

If you have more questions, write a comment.