# How to upload the stored data when internet access available?

Tags: android, ios

I am trying to develop Android and iOS app. I am trying to store the user input in the storage and upload them when the user can access internet. Is there any API/library I can use to implement this function?

Comment: Don't understand, why someone downvoted this Question ? +1 to this Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a BroadCastReceiver class for internet connectivity change, define the same in  manifest file. [Connectivity BroadCast Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140061/broadcast-receiver-and-internet-connection)
2. Create a class which extends [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), to upload you records (write network stuff here)
3. In BroadCast Receiver class check for Data Connection if its true then start IntentService.
4. Test it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write function on the background of the app thet send **Json** to the server and get from the server.

Link To use onbackground in android Cus i android devlopement [Asyngtask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250989/how-to-use-asynctask-correctly-android)

its easy to learn and use **Json**.

Hope its help...